# How can you identify the source window for a drag operation in a Cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop

I have a document based application in which the window has a split view. The left pane is a NSOutlineView and the right is a canvas that displays elements.

I currently have dragging and dropping supported for both the canvas and the outline view (both should have the same Pasteboard Type and should be able to drop on either the right or left pane).

I would like to figure out how I can identify the source window of the drag. This way I can disable dropping on the canvas or NSOutlineView within the same window. I see that NSDraggingInfo has a draggingSource property but I am not able to use that because it is not the originating window. It also has a draggingDestinationWindow property but not one for the source.

Any idea how I can work around this?

---

### Update

With the push to use draggingSource from Will I revisited my code and realized that I was overlooking the use of draggingSource because sometimes I also handle drags from the Finder which would crash when I tried to access the window property of NSView.

I have updated my protocol implementation of the below methods

```
- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender
- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender


id<NSDraggingSource> dragSource = [sender draggingSource];
if ( [dragSource respondsToSelector:@selector(window)] && [(NSView *)dragSource window] == [self window])
    return NO;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is all within one app, you should be able to use `draggingSource`

```
This method returns nil if the source is not in the same application as the destination. The dragging source implements methods from the NSDraggingSource protocol.
```

Comment: Thanks Will, I updated my question with the actual solution I built based on your suggestion. It seems a bit "hacky" to me though - does this look like a good solution?

Comment: I don’t know how your drag is done can you just check if `(dragSource == self)`?

Comment: The problem is in the left pane the dragSource is an NSOutlineView and in the right it is an NSView. But the two panes should not accept drags from one-another if they are from the same window - only if it is from another document. (Think two photoshop documents - you can drag from the layers list or the canvas onto another document. But you cannot drag from the layers list of one document onto its own canvas)